# How many bytes to use for data type int and varchar to optimize?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to optimize my space by defining optimal bytes for given data types in SQL.

**Question 1:** 
If I know that the column 'US zip code' can only have 5 characters, then would I use char(5) in this case or something else?

**Question 2:** 
If I know that the column 'house_shape_code' can have UP TO have 7 characters, then would I use int(7) in this case or something else?

I would appreciate guidance here, so I can optimize the creation of my database.

Thanks.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Answer on question 1 is correct, answer question 2 is incorrect `int(7)` the `(7)` part does not limit storage in anny way `int(7)` and `int` have the same storage requirements. that `(7)` part is only used with zerofill option..

Answer (score 0):

Do not focus on micro-optimizations.  It is unlikely that you have enough data for this really to make much of a difference.

For US zip codes use either `CHAR(5)` or `CHAR(9)`, depending on whether you want 5- or 9- digit zip codes.  (You might even choose `CHAR(10)` to include the hyphen.)  Do not use a numeric type, because leading zeros are relevant.

For the second example, I would probably recommend `VARCHAR(7)`.  You don't have a numeric value, so there is not a requirement to use a number -- addition and multiplication don't make sense.

You can still use a number (after all, primary keys are typically numbers).  If so, a 4-byte number is fine -- and preferable for indexes, because fixed length keys are an iota more efficient.  You can also use a numeric, `numeric(7, 0)`.

Base the type on the right type to represent the value you need, not on some notion of optimization.  It is unlikely that the choice of type will have much impact on your queries.